File view doesn't shows system properly. (Onedrive, icloud missing)
When I try to save or open something in Blender, the file view doesn't shows locations on my mac properly. I see just Mac HD.
I checked Privacy and Sec/Files and Folders already. I am not able to switch on/off anything but it shows that it has full access. I have my files uploaded to Icloud and Onedrive, but I cannot see in Blender.
I have macbook, Sonoma 14.5 / Blender 4.11


a workaround is dragging your icloud drive (from finder in the bottom bar) into the volume of the open files dialog of blender  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/yrNtm4m0.png
